# awk replacing text but not for the last line

Tags: unix, awk, gawk

i tried the awk liner below(on windows command-prompt):not working properly

```
gawk -v var="hot" "{ if(!NR){gsub(/cool/,var,$0) ;print} else{print}}" awk_test
```

input file is below

```
 this is a cool jack
 this nota cool kack
 this obviously a cool jack
```

a unix solution is also feasible

Comment: The condition `(!NR)` is always false because NR (the current record number) is always a positive integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -vvar="hot" '{gsub("cool",hot,t);print t}{t=$0}END{print}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
sed '$d' yourfile | sed 's/cool/hot/g' > newfile
tail -1 yourfile >> newfile
```

this should do the substitution on everything but the last line of the file first, and then add the last line of the original file.

Comment: this is ok ...but i dont have sed in my command prompt.i only have gawk.so i need an awk/gawk solution. what is actually wrong with my gawk script.

Answer (score 0):

You could also pass the number of lines as a parameter:

```
gawk -v var=hot -v lines=$(wc -l < test.txt) '
    NR != lines {gsub(/cool/, var)} 
    {print}
' test.txt
```